# TSQL Inner Select with SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the sum of 2 values in my inner select but get an error about the aggregate function.

I am just trying to understand how I need to format this differently to get it working.

Is there a different order I need to do this in?

```
 (SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.[booksCost],1) AS booksCost, 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.[tuitionCost],1) AS tuitionCost,
           SUM (D.[booksCost] + D.[tuitionCost]) AS totalCost,
           D.[className]
  FROM   tuitionApplicationClasses AS D
  WHERE  applicationID = A.[applicationID]
  FOR    XML PATH ('classData'), TYPE, ELEMENTS),


Column 'tuitionApplicationClasses.booksCost' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: You can't `SUM` and then also `SELECT` single columns in a single query - this is because your `SUM` is essentially grouping all rows into a single group and running an aggregate over them. You can use a correlated subquery to do this - `(SELECT SUM(booksCost + tuitionCost) FROM tuitionApplicationClasses WHERE applicationID = A.applicationID) as totalCost` in place of your original `SUM` - (I'm not actually sure where A is aliased in the query, I can't see it so the above may not be correct...)

Comment: The only issue is I am trying to get the sum of those 2 values as there are multiple rows in the select. There could be 10 results and I need the total of each row (class) by adding the tuition + books together. So its not just an overall sum of the whole application but each row in the inner select.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested in my comment yet? It's called a correlated subquery because it uses fields from the outer query and runs once per outer row (e.g. once per row it will sum the books and tuition cost based on the applicationID assuming that is the unique key)

Comment: I did, and its giving me the same total of everything for all 10 records returned where each record should have its own total

Comment: That's almost it then - you need to make sure you relate the inner subquery to the outer query by what makes it unique - unless of course you actually don't want an aggregate (have you tried it without SUM? - i.e. are you looking to just add booksCosts and tuition cost per row or do you want an aggregate across a set?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) is an aggregate function that is applied over the specified column in a query. What you are trying to do is simply add the first two columns in every row, so you need to modify the query to drop the `SUM` keyword.

```
(SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.[booksCost],1) AS booksCost, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.[tuitionCost],1) AS tuitionCost,
       (D.[booksCost] + D.[tuitionCost]) AS totalCost,
       D.[className]
FROM   tuitionApplicationClasses AS D
WHERE  applicationID = A.[applicationID]
FOR    XML PATH ('classData'), TYPE, ELEMENTS),
```

Comment: This worked, for some reason I thought sum was needed for doing addition within a query

Comment: Ah - that simple :) I overlooked the most obvious interpretation!

Answer (score 0):

Try use SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY..)

```
(SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.[booksCost],1) AS booksCost, 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR,D.[tuitionCost],1) AS tuitionCost,
           SUM (D.[booksCost] + D.[tuitionCost]) OVER (PARTITON BY applicationID) AS totalCost,
           D.[className]
  FROM   tuitionApplicationClasses AS D
  WHERE  applicationID = A.[applicationID]
  FOR    XML PATH ('classData'), TYPE, ELEMENTS),
```

Answer (score 0):

When not doing an operation on a field you must include it in a GROUP BY statement that contains the other fields not used in the operation functions.